# Javascript: Add same <li> to mulitple <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got following code:

```
var someUL1 = document.getElementById("someUl_1");
var someUL2 = document.getElementById("someUl_2");

someArray.forEach(function (anItem) {
     var li = document.createElement("LI");
     li.setAttribute("value", anItem);

     var p = document.createElement("P");
     p.innerHTML = anItem;
     li.appendChild(p);

     someUL1.appendChild(li);
     someUL2.appendChild(li);
});
```

this one just adds all items from the array to the "someUL2".

But this one:

```
var someUL1 = document.getElementById("someUl_1");
var someUL2 = document.getElementById("someUl_2");

someArray.forEach(function (anItem) {
     var li = document.createElement("LI");
     li.setAttribute("value", anItem);
     li.innerHTML = anItem;

     var li2 = document.createElement("LI");
     li2.setAttribute("value", anItem);
     li2.innerHTML = anItem;

     someUL1.appendChild(li);
     someUL2.appendChild(li2);
});
```

does.

Why won't the first one add the items out of the array into both "UL's"?

Comment: show the html code, please!

Comment: I guess in your second example, it is `someUL2.appendChild(li2);` instead of `someUL2.appendChild(li);`. Now to answer question, `appendChild` called on already apended element just move it to new location. So in first example, you just append `li` to first `ul` and then move the same `li` element to the second `ul`

Comment: Can you show how `someArray` lookes like? what is inside this array?